# How do I brew Vietnamese Coffee in a phin filter without getting too watered down?

Tags: drip-brew, vietnam, phin

How do I brew Vietnamese Coffee without it tasting too watered down? I'm using a phin filter, but I can't get the coffee to be strong as I typically get at the restaurants. I tried applying more pressure to the coffee grounds to slow down the drip and less finely ground coffee.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it works well with a phin, if you grind the beans as for filter coffee, use two heaped tea-spoons and moderately press down the metal plate with the holes. And a good quality of the beans helps.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest changing your coffee brand, some coffee powder are more or less thin and therefore, making your coffee more or less strong.

One easy to find brand I find really good to make a strong coffee is the Illy classico.

I also suggest wetting a little the coffee powder before applying a very gentle pressure with the metal plate with the holes

Comment: Wetting the coffee grids before applying pressure sounds great! I used the coffee beans from the same company I bought the phin from, so not sure if it's the coffee itself? It's still worth testing out. Thanks.